# DataGridView does not automatically appear when form loads

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How can I show the datagridview after the form loads?? Because after my form loads my datagridview looks like this. I just want to make my data in the datagridview visible after my form loads. The data appears when I type at the searchbar(not automatic).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q1ql.jpg)

Comment: If you are able to fill the gridview with data on your search function then just call the same code on your form_load event

Comment: ok sir thank you. ill try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

***Firstly,*** please post the code for your `DataGridView`, as it is much easier if you provide us code to deal with.

So, let's get this issue fixed.

One problem could be, is that you're making a `sub` or a `function`, ***but you're never calling it.***

What I mean by that is, if you create a `sub` or a `function` but you never call it, then it won't usually do anything, but for your case, since you want the `DataGridView` to show on startup (`Form_Load`), you need to call your `sub` or `function` in `Form_Load`.

So, what I suggest you doing is this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    // your code here which would be your sub or function
End Sub
```

Since you're now calling your `sub` or `function` in `Form1_Load`, your `DataGridView` will now show on the form when it first loads.

> Edit: Changed some text around to make the answer make more sense.

Comment: @arusocse please press the 'tick' icon if this helped you!